# USB Type-C PD Trigger/Dummy/Decoy Boards

Tags: usb-pd

I want to make a 10 ports usb-c PD bank regarding to this.
Perhaps a simple question but i have never worked with these:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Trigger-Module-Pdc004-Voltage-Release/dp/B0BGL4YNGG (‎TKSEco6h9aqu03)
[image]
there simple chips to provide power output.
Now what confuses me is: it has different variations (or some boards have settings) 5v-9v-12v-15v-20v But isn't the whole point of the PD protocol to deliver the requested power ? aka plugin usb -c 5v 1a device it requests that voltage.
So how should i see these boards they are set to one voltage aka 20v and will fry any device that can't handle it ?

Comment: i would get a few cheap 12v cigarette lighter > USB-C+PD adapters; 20W ones are dirt-cheap and 45W ones are under $20. These will turn your 12-ish volt power source into whatever the USB-C device wants to use; the opposite of a trigger if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not boards to provide power to a Type-C  power sink. These are boards to take power from Type-C power source.

So you can't make a power bank with these.

These will request e.g. 9V or 20V from the power source and provide you that voltage as output so you can connect your device to a standard Type-C laptop charger for example.

Comment: What base chip can do the opposite ?

Comment: @SpaceCabbie In a power supply, there would be a chip that negotiates what the power supply is capable of and what the device requests. But alone that ia not useful, as the chip must then control the power supply to somehow change the voltage the device requested. You need the whole system, not just a chip. And besides, 10 ports of USB Type-C means if you want all 10 ports to be active at the same time, that is a huge amount of watts. At minimum all devices can draw 900mA at 5V which already is 9A or 45W, even without PD. For each port to be useful you need much more.